# Using both stat_bin computed variables and stepping through a vector of the same length as data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to label the bars in a histogram. The basic code works fine:

```
mtcars <- as_tibble(mtcars)
bw <- 2
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = cyl)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = bw) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth = bw, geom = "text", vjust = -.5, aes(label = ..count..))
```

However, I'm dealing with a dataset that has some bins resulting in a count of 0. This can be simulated above by changing the binwidth to 1: `bw <- 1`. Since there are no odd numbers, 5 and 7 will be labeled 0. Because I want 0's to just be blank, I can do something like this:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = cyl)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = bw) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth = bw, geom = "text", vjust = -.5, aes(label = ifelse(..count.. > 0, ..count.., "")))
```

So far so good. I can also use a vector of characters for the label. Here's an example:

```
bw <- 1
labs <- letters[1:5]
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = cyl)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = bw) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth = bw, geom = "text", vjust = -.5, label = labs)
```

Note that 1) the vector must be of the same length as the number of bins and 2) `label` can no longer be inside `aes`. Violating either of those will result in `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (x): label` where `x` is 5 in the first case and 32 in the second.

Here lies the problem: I want to once again hide labels for bins that have a count 0 *and* use a vector of characters to label the bins, but I can't use and `ifelse` expression with `..count..` anymore because it can't be accessed outside `aes`, nor can I use `labs` inside `aes` without having to assign a value to each data point as opposed to each bin. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Have you tried `aes(label = ifelse(..count.. > 0, labs, ""))`?  This definitely relies having the same length of labels as bins and knowing the labels are in the correct order.

Comment: @aosmith I didn't try because `aes(label = labs)` didn't work, but I just tried it out and it worked like a charm! I still don't understand how this works though. Clearly it's not the same as, say,  `ifelse(-2:2 > 0, letters[1:5], "")`, which returns `[1] ""  ""  ""  "d" "e"` and doesn't work (just tried). If that's the case, what exactly is `ifelse(..count.. > 0, labs, "")`? Is there a `..count..` generated for each row? If you could provide a brief explanation as an answer, I'll mark this question as answered! Thanks!

Comment: I haven't looked into the internals at all but, yes, it makes sense to me that the plotted dataset has a `..count..` for each row.  I don't have time to investigate this morning, but take a look at something like `ggplot_build(plotname)$data[[1]]` (where plotname is the name of the plot you've made) to see what's in the plotting dataset.